# Transferring contacts from one CiviCRM installation to another

Tags: contacts

I have two different Civi installation on different servers. I want to move all contacts from one CRM to another one(to a new group). Total contacts are more than 15k. I have facing some error if I export more than 1000 contacts and the same thing on Import also If I tried to upload more than 1000 contacts getting 500 server error.

Please let know if there is any software available for transferring contacts.

_Ashwin

Comment: Curious. Why are you wanting to do this

Answer (score 3):

Please increase your max_execution_time

if you are using Xamp look for following file and change

xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries for config.default.php

change 
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300; to 0 - for unlimited

this should fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

The errors you're experiencing are related to your hosting environment rather than CiviCRM, so it's difficult to make suggestions without knowing more about your hosting environment.  However, I would recommend the following:

- The best solution is to set up a development server under your own control - perhaps on your local computer.
- Increasing the max execution time as Ramesh suggests.
- Use the command line export tools, if you're comfortable with SSH.  See here: https://civicrm.org/blogs/xavier/api_batch_tools
- There's a class of tools called "ETL" that are designed for this exact purpose.  I often use Kettle, a free ETL tool, to do what you're describing (usually migrating from other software into CiviCRM).  However, ETL tools have a steep learning curve - for what you want, you're best off using the command line tool and/or a development server.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I have not seen issues with exports of contacts.

However, CiviCRM generally has issues with large imports.

My usual recommendation is to write a php script that reads through the import file record by record and inserts them using the CiviCRM API.

Theoretically, you could set things up to use the API to read the old CiviCRM to get a record, and then the API to insert in the new one.  (Kinda interesting application that.)